# Check Salesforce User/Profile for Permission to Send Mass E-mail using Apex/SOQL?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

On the Profile page in Salesforce, there's an permission checkbox for Mass Email. How can I query this value using Apex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Profile object has a bunch of fields named like PermissionXXX that indicate whether a profile has a certain permission. I just checked, and in my org, I don't see a permission field for mass emailing. So either my org doesn't have this feature (I dont' think this is the case), or more likely, salesforce chose not to expose this permission on the Permission object. If the latter is true, there may not be a way to check, other than try/catch, which you could treat as a permission check.

Comment: If you think it would be useful to others, please consider submitting this as an Idea on success.salesforce.com.  I'm trying to get them to open up other settings currently only available through the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

There is a section email limts in the above page and it specifies all your mits for mass email and individual email.